# Laravel: Order by column value count?

Tags: php, laravel

I used to have a query like this

```
$topReferrals = User::orderBy('user_referrals', 'DESC')->get();
```

Recently I changed my database structure to not count user_referrals for each user in an int datatype, but to have a column for each user called `referred_by` and have its value who they have been referred by, I need to adapt my query to work with the new system.

I'm not quite sure how I would go about this, I was hoping someone could help?

Comment: Is there a system in with there are users and some other users which are referred by some users ? you didn't explain it well .. Do you want to query the referrer easily ??

Comment: Each user has a column `referred_by`, I'm trying to get the all of them in order of who has the most referrals (determined by if `referred_by` equals to their username).

Answer (score 0):

As I’ve understood the question, I think this is how I’d approach getting the number of referrals per user..

```
$all = User::all();
foreach ($all as $current) {
    $current->referrals = User::where('referred_by', $current)->count();
}
$all->sortBy('referrals');
```

$all should now be a list of users sorted by the number of referrals.

Comment: Do I need a column in my database to do this? Or is Laravel clever enough to just create a temp variable on the model?

Comment: Laravel is clever enough to create a temporary variable

Comment: I'm 1 step away from marking this as the accepted answer, although you haven't explained how you put them in order of the `referrals` variable after setting it.

Comment: I’d suggest using the sortBy method on the collection, I’ll update the answer to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `referred_by` column in `User` table as it denotes foreign key linked to the user.

Use query below to get count of users that have been referred for each referrer:

`User::where('referred_by', $referred_user_id)->count();`

OR

`User::where('referred_by', $referred_user_id)->orderByDesc('referred_by')->get();`

**Note:** Just make sure you have created a table for referrers to store all the details for referrers in case you want to grabs other data regarding them. You just need to add relations to the `User` model to directly access to the database.

```
public function hasReferrers () {
    $this->hasOne('App\Referrer');
}
```

Where `App\Referrer` is model for your referrers table.

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent offers several means of [counting relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models). One approach would be to set the `$withCount` property on the `User` model:

```
// assuming your model has a referrals method.
protected $withCount = ['referrals'];
```

This will append an attribute on each queried model that can be used in subsequent queries or collection modifications.

```
User::all()->sortByDesc('referrals');
```